# Обращение к Ajax из foreach php

Tags: php, ajax

прошу помощи.
Есть скрипт постов, на нем лайки.

+1 происходит по клику `<div id="like" data-id="'.$posting['id'].'">'.$posting['like'].'</div>.`
Проблема в том что, +1 происходит только на последнюю запись из цикла `foreach`.
На следующие  `ajax` не реагирует.

вот цикл `foreach php`

```
        foreach ( $pjk as $posting ) {
            echo '<div class="col-auto" id="text_posting_user" data-id="'.$posting['id'].'" style="padding: 1.7em; padding-bottom: 0;"><div class="postings"><div class="bord-ava_post" style="background-image: url(' . $user_prof->avatar .');"></div><p><span style="font-weight: bold;">'.$posting['user_login'].'</span><span >X</span><br>
                <span class="datePost">'.$posting['dataname'].'</span> 
                <span class="dateTime">'.$posting['time'].'</span></span></p>
                </div>
                <div class="text_p"><p>'.$posting['post'].'</p></div>
                <hr style="margin-bottom: 0.5rem;">
                <div class="b_funk_post">
                <div id="like" data-id="'.$posting['id'].'">'.$posting['like'].'</div>  
                </div>
                <div>
                    <textarea placeholder="Напишите комментарий..." style="margin-top: 4px;margin-bottom: 4px;border-radius: 30px;height: 35px;font-size: x-small;"></textarea>
                </div>
                </div>';
         }
```

и `ajax`

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#like").bind("click", function(event) {
    var dit = $(this).attr("data-id");    
      $.ajax({
        url: "ajaxLike.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: ("id=" +dit),
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(result) {
          if (result) {
            $("#like").text(Number($("#like").text()) + 1);
          }
          else alert("Error");
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Значение атрибута `id` должно быть уникальным. Используйте `class`

```
<div class="like" data-id="'.$posting['id'].'">'.$posting['like'].'</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".like").bind("click", function(event) {
...
```